# Why does json.dumps(list(np.arange(5))) fail while json.dumps(np.arange(5).tolist()) works

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I noticed this problem when a computer running Ubuntu was updated recently and the default version of Python changed to 2.7.

```
import json
import numpy as np

json.dumps(list(np.arange(5))) # Fails, throws a "TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable"
json.dumps(np.arange(5).tolist()) # Works
```

Is there a difference between list() and the tolist() methd of a numpy array?

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem, where I cannot `json.dumps()` a np.int64 variable. However, it works for me in Python 2.7.9 but not in 3.4.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like the `tolist()` method turns the numpy `int32` (or whatever size you have) back into an `int`, which JSON knows what to do with:

```
>>> list(np.arange(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> type(list(np.arange(5)))
<type 'list'>
>>> type(list(np.arange(5))[0])
<type 'numpy.int32'>
>>> np.arange(5).tolist()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> type(np.arange(5).tolist())
<type 'list'>
>>> type(np.arange(5).tolist()[0])
<type 'int'>
```

As the docs say for `tolist()`:

> Return the array as a (possibly nested) list.
>
> Return a copy of the array data as a (nested) Python list. **Data items
>   are converted to the nearest compatible Python type.**

The last line makes the difference here.

Comment: Do you know if this a recent change? The code used to work before the system got upgraded.

Comment: Not sure, I'm afraid-- not even sure if the change was in numpy (say a type renaming) or on the Python JSON side (maybe it used to try harder to deal with unknown types?)

Comment: [Simple solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/python-sets-are-not-json-serializable) by explicitly passing a [default handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) for non-serializable objects.

Answer (score 23):

Because the elements of a NumPy array are not native ints, but of NUmPy's own types:

```
>>> type(np.arange(5)[0])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

You can use a custom [`JSONEncoder`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) to support the `ndarray` type returned by `arange`:

```
import numpy as np
import json

class NumPyArangeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist() # or map(int, obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

print(json.dumps(np.arange(5), cls=NumPyArangeEncoder))
```

Comment: great answer! can you please also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154853/using-json-dumps-to-serialize-class-with-dictionary-with-ndarray)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with the first you don't get an int. You get a numpy.int64. That cannot be serialized.