# Python: Interesting json.dumps serialization quirk

Tags: json, python-2.7, numpy

I have a fairly complicated dictionary that I want to convert into a JSON object.

```
dataj = json.dumps(post_data)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 6 is not JSON serializable
```

However, if I print my dictionary:

```
print post_data
```

And I copy/paste this post_data back into the same variable:

```
post_data = pasted data
```

Json.dumps works.  No idea why this is happening but I suspect it has something to do with proper line breaks when copying the text and pasting it back in.  Any way I can avoid having to do this?

Comment: Are you using any libraries like NumPy? I've found many NumPy types aren't JSON serializable even though they *look like* primitive numbers.

Comment: I believe some of my ints are numpy ints yes -- do these convert to primitive numbers after I copy and paste?

Comment: Yes, that's what would happen. I'll think about ways to auto-convert these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using NumPy; I've run into this problem before.

NumPy represents non-serializable *primitive-like* data types as primitives when `print`ing them. When you copy and paste the output, you're taking that text and re-entering it as an actual primitive (which is JSON serializable, of course).

So you basically have 2 options: refactor the code to [use NumPy's `.tolist()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562009/1255748) (and related functions) or [enhance the JSON serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562008/1255748) to accept NumPy datatypes.