# Python Pandas: use native types

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to know if I can use native types for number in a pandas DataFrame instead of numpy types.

I try to convert from numpy to native int with this code:

```
# Convert numpy to native type
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(int)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # If this is a numpy type then it has an item method
    if hasattr(df['a'][index], 'item'):
        df['a'][index] = df['a'][index].item()
```

But when I check the type, it is always a numpy.int64

Comment: Hope this will help [NUMPY TYPES TO NATIVE TYPES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @hpaulj i want my dataframe to be serializable, but numpy.int are not.

Comment: A `numpy` array stores its data in a contiguous buffer.  If dtype is int, those bytes would be the same a Python ints.  It's the public interface that gives `df['a'][1]` that `np.int64` wrapper.  It is still a numpy object, regardless of `dtype`.  It's the `.item()` method that takes it out of the numpy wrapper.  How are 'serializing' this data?

Comment: Look at `np.lib.npyio.format` or `numpy/lib/format.py` to see how `np.save` writes an array to a file.

Comment: In addition, don't confuse `type` (a Python concept) and `dtype` (a numpy attribute).

Comment: *"i want my dataframe to be serializable,"* Don't put this info in the comments; [edit] your question instead. it makes it different from the question mentioned by @TanmayaMeher.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561932/  - SO question on why JSON `dumps` works on `a.tolist()` but not on `list(a)`.  One produces a list of `int`, the other a list of `np.int`.