# Convert custom class to standard Python type

Tags: python, numpy, casting

I was working with a `numpy` array called `predictions`. I was playing around with the following code:

```
print type(predictions)
print list(predictions)
```

The output was:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`
[u'yes', u'no', u'yes', u'yes', u'yes']
```

I was wondering how `numpy` managed to build their `ndarray` class so that it could be converted to a list not with their own `list` function, but with the standard Python function.

Python version: 2.7, Numpy version: 1.9.2

Comment: Note that `list(whatever)` will work if `whatever.__iter__` is implemented - i.e. Python will consume the iterator and put each resulting object into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have answered from the pure Python perspective below, but `numpy`'s
>   arrays are actually implemented in C - see e.g. [the `array_iter`
>   function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c#L1760).

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list) defines the argument to `list` as an `iterable`; `new_list = list(something)` works a little bit like:

```
new_list = []
for element in something:
    new_list.append(element)
```

(or, in a list comprehension: `new_list = [element for element in something]`). Therefore to implement this behaviour for a custom class, you need to define the [`__iter__` magic method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

```
>>> class Demo(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((1, 2, 3))


>>> list(Demo())
[1, 2, 3]
```

Note that conversion to other types will require [different](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__) [methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

Answer (score 2):

As others have written, `list()` works because an array is an iterable.  It is equivalent to `[i for i in arr]`.  To understand it you need to understand how iteration over an array works.  In particular, `list(arr)` is not the same as `arr.tolist()`.

```
In [685]: arr=np.array('one two three four'.split())

In [686]: arr
Out[686]: 
array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [687]: ll=list(arr)

In [688]: ll
Out[688]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

In [689]: type(ll[0])
Out[689]: numpy.str_

In [690]: ll1=arr.tolist()

In [691]: ll1
Out[691]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

In [692]: type(ll1[0])
Out[692]: str
```

The print display of `ll` and `ll1` looks the same, but the `type` of the elements is different, one is a `str`, the other a `str` wrapped in a `numpy` class.  That distinction has come up in a recent question about serializing an array.

The distinction becomes more obvious when `arr` is 2d.  Simple interation then produces the rows, not the elements:

```
In [693]: arr=np.reshape(arr,(2,2))

In [694]: arr
Out[694]: 
array([['one', 'two'],
       ['three', 'four']], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [695]: list(arr)
Out[695]: 
[array(['one', 'two'], 
       dtype='<U5'), array(['three', 'four'], 
       dtype='<U5')]

In [696]: arr.tolist()
Out[696]: [['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four']]
```

`list(arr)` is now two arrays, while `arr.tolist()` is a nested list.

[Python Pandas: use native types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536440/python-pandas-use-native-types#comment51060060_31536440)

[Why does json.dumps(list(np.arange(5))) fail while json.dumps(np.arange(5).tolist()) works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561932/why-does-json-dumpslistnp-arange5-fail-while-json-dumpsnp-arange5-tolis)