# How to serialize dictionary with array value to json in django

Tags: json, django, serialization

I have a dictionary which contains few keys with numpy array as its value. I want to seriaize this dictionary to json. I have used json.dumps but it is giving me an issue( array object is not json serializable). Is there a way in django i can serialize this dictionary to json?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the exact stack trace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable