# How to visualize bad predictions in keras?

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, keras, text-processing

I'm working on a text classification problem, **I'd like to know exacly for which input I got wrong prediction** at validation. Is there a way to do that in Keras? 
I imagine something like a column bar graph for bad predictions. (X sentence length, Y quantity/occurrence)

I've found [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/) article about visalisation but it's kinda different what I need. I'm making very few epochs so this method is not showing any information for me.

I'm aware that I can [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061457/keras-how-to-save-the-training-history/41066859) the history of the training but as far as I know

thank you for reading my post.

**EDIT:**

My current dataframe looks like this:

```
+----------------+----------+
|    sentence    | language |
+----------------+----------+
| test sentence. | english  |
+----------------+----------+
```

And after validaiton I'd like to get something like this as pythonic833 suggested:

```
+----------------+----------+-----------+
|    sentence    | language | validated |
+----------------+----------+-----------+
| test sentence. | english  | english   |
+----------------+----------+-----------+
```

Can I achive this during training (I have seperate validation dataset) or should I just use `model.predict` and construct it by myself?

Comment: I can just give you some general thoughts about this: construct a dataframe df with the following form: X,Y_true,Y_pred. Then you can construct a dataframe df_wrong_class = df[df[Y_true] != df[Y_pred]] and analyze this. For that you can use groupby or any of the pandas visualization tools. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I'd like to use pandas to later on but I'm not quite sure how to get the valdiated values to a dataframe.