# How to parse string representation back to numpy array?

Tags: opencv, numpy, redis

I used opencv to read an image and save it to redis like this:

```
frame=cv2.imread('/path/to/image.png')
rd.set('frame', frame)
```

then,read it back a string representation like this:

```
[[[ 38  45  51]
  [ 38  45  51]
  [ 38  45  51]
  ..., 

  [235 217 222]]]
```

then I tried to get it back like this:

```
frameString=rd.get('frame')
mat=np.array(frameString)
```

but

```
 print mat.shape
```

output

```
 ()
```

then I tried

```
 mat=eval(frameString)
```

this gives me error:

```
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    [[[ 38  45  51]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

question is

```
how to convert this string representation back to numpy array correctly?
```

Comment: `pickle.dumps` is a better way of generating a string representation of a numpy array.  It, in effect, uses `np.save` to serialize the array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to encode it as JSON and save that to redis.

```
frame=cv2.imread('/path/to/image.png')
rd.set('frame', json.dumps(frame. tolist()))


frameString=json.loads(rd.get('frame'))
mat=np.array(frameString)
```

You can find faster and more compact serialization formats though.

Comment: ,rd.set('frame', json.dumps(frame)) tells '...is not JSON serializable'

Comment: You should provide a way to convert it to a normal array or alike

Comment: I don't think numpy arrays are JSON serializable either. You'd have to `tolist()` it first. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26646362/

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't worked with numpy in a long while. modifying my answer as per @hpaulj's reference.