# mpld3 results in TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, mpld3

If I run

```
    import pandas as pd
    import mpld3
    import seaborn as sns
    df = pd.DataFrame([(1,3),(2,-1)],columns= ['a','b'])
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    sns.regplot('a', 'b', df)
```

works fine.
If I add

```
    mpld3.enable_notebook()
```

I obtain error:
Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Do you have any suggestion about what is causing this annoyance with mpld3?

For what I can understand, this is not the same question asked in [NumPy array is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable)
In my question I'm asking how to make mpld3 work or at least not making everything else not working.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am getting the same error. BTW this is definitely not a duplicate question..

Comment: Hi @JoãoAbrantes I've not solved it, I just decide to avoid mpld3 for good

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, since we can't access the serializer.

Comment: You can find a solution at https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/441 which consists of class NumpyEncoder replacement