# Json serialization error using matplotlib mpld3 with LinkedBrush

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

The `mpld3` (`matplotlib` on `d3`) example for `LinkedBrush` 
http://mpld3.github.io/examples/linked_brush.html provides the following code example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins, utils


data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

# dither the data for clearer plotting
X += 0.1 * np.random.random(X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 4, sharex="col", sharey="row", figsize=(8, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95,
                    hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        points = ax[3 - i, j].scatter(X[:, j], X[:, i],
                                      c=y, s=40, alpha=0.6)

# remove tick labels
for axi in ax.flat:
    for axis in [axi.xaxis, axi.yaxis]:
        axis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())

# Here we connect the linked brush plugin
plugins.connect(fig, plugins.LinkedBrush(points))

mpld3.show()
```

While the public web page shows the matrix of linked outputs, when running it locally there is a `json` serialization error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/scalatesting/src/main/python/mpld3_linkedbrush.py", line 34, in <module>
    mpld3.show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpld3/_display.py", line 358, in show
    html = fig_to_html(fig, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpld3/_display.py", line 251, in fig_to_html
    figure_json=json.dumps(figure_json, cls=NumpyEncoder),
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpld3/_display.py", line 138, in default
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: array([ 1.]) is not JSON serializable
```

The local environment is

```
$pip show mpld3
Name: mpld3
Version: 0.3
Summary: D3 Viewer for Matplotlib
Home-page: http://mpld3.github.com
Author: Jake VanderPlas
Author-email: jakevdp@cs.washington.edu
License: BSD 3-clause
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and

```
$python -V
Python 2.7.14
```

The `mpld3` was installed today.  Is there an `mpld3` versioning issue? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems to be an instance of [this bug](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/434), same solution is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable - call `points.tolist()` before conecting the plugin

Comment: @snakecharmerb Feel free to make this an answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on a comment from @snakecharmerb I forked from `mpld3`, entered the suggested fix, and pip installed from my new branch on github.

The fix is here:  https://github.com/javadba/mpld3/tree/display_fix . It may be installed via:

```
python -m pip install --user "git+https://github.com/javadba/mpld3@display_fix"
```

It works well: the `json serialization` error is gone and the linkage among the 9 charts functions properly:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe they still didn't take in your PR. This caused me HOURS to find out. Thank you for this btw!!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution given [here](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/434#issuecomment-340255689) did not work.

I had a networkx graph to visualize:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

import networkx as nx
G = nx.path_graph(4)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(facecolor='#EEEEEE'))
scatter = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax)

labels = G.nodes()
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(scatter, labels=labels)
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.show()
```

Then it gave the "JSON not serializable" error. I found the above link, and tried the fix. The fix essentially says that if the object is of type `numpy.ndarray`, then change it to list.

But the object type of `G.nodes` is `networkx.classes.reportviews.NodeView`, not `numpy.ndarray`; thus it wasn't working.

So, I modified the file `_display.py` to add `import networkx` and added the following 2 lines in the `default` function in class `NumpyEncoder` to make it work:

```
elif isinstance(obj,networkx.classes.reportviews.NodeView):
    return list(obj)
```

Now it works:

[image]

Comment: So it appears that the solution for various data types require class-specific tweaks. Thanks for updating