# mpld3: stackplot causes serialization error

Tags: mpld3

I'm trying to use mpld3 to render a stack plot and am running into an issue when fig_to_html tries to serialize.  It looks like it's running into the issue with NumPy described here:

[NumPy array is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable#32850511)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 32, in
>   
>       mpld3.show()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpld3/_display.py", line 358,
>   in show
>       html = fig_to_html(fig, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpld3/_display.py", line 251,
>   in fig_to_html
>       figure_json=json.dumps(figure_json, cls=NumpyEncoder),   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py",
>   line 238, in dumps
>       **kw).encode(obj)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
>   line 199, in encode
>       chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
>   line 257, in iterencode
>       return _iterencode(o, 0)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpld3/_display.py", line 138,
>   in default
>       return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
>   line 180, in default
>       o.**class**.**name**) TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Here's my plotting code for reference; plt.show() works fine.  This only seems to be an issue with the stackplot, the regular plot is fine.

```
# get x,y,labels

# do plotting
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
#fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for yval in range(len(y)):
    ax1.plot(x, y[yval], label=labels[yval])

ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

ax2.stackplot(x, y, labels=labels)
ax2.legend(loc='upper left')
ax2.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

#plt.show()
mpld3.show()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json serialization error using matplotlib mpld3 with LinkedBrush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380865/json-serialization-error-using-matplotlib-mpld3-with-linkedbrush)

Answer (score 0):

Look like this is a duplicate of:
[MPLD3 with Python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015030/mpld3-with-python-error)

which you may need since mpld3 is not maintained anymore.