# Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable in mpld3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, mpld3

I want to get the interaсtive Matplotlib window in IPython notebook. I have several 2D points and I want to draw this. So I do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
plt.scatter(points[0], points[1], color='r')
mpld3.show()
```

But I get error `Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable`. So how can I win it?

Comment: I find another library for building interactive graphics. And it helps me. It's https://plot.ly/python/.

Comment: Here is a [Fix for the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380865/json-serialization-error-using-matplotlib-mpld3-with-linkedbrush) Also, you can read here [more details for the cause of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015030/mpld3-with-python-error)

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380865/json-serialization-error-using-matplotlib-mpld3-with-linkedbrush

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json serialization error using matplotlib mpld3 with LinkedBrush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380865/json-serialization-error-using-matplotlib-mpld3-with-linkedbrush)