# Sending Numpy array to a webhook for Hangouts Chat API with Python?

Tags: python, google-hangouts

I've set up a webhook in a chat room in my Google Hangouts Chat.

I can successfully run their example code, which generates a message from the bot associated with the webhook in the chat:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from json import dumps

#
# Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart
#
def main():
    url = '<INCOMING-WEBHOOK-URL>'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : 'Hello World!'}

    message_headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I try to sent a Numpy Array with the code:

```
bot_message = {
            'text' : NumpyArrayObject}
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable
```

Using Python list I got the error:

```
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \\"text\\" at \'message\': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list."\n          }\n        ]\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that a `NumPy` array is an object, presumably w/a variety of struct/binary/metadata, and can't be directly serialized (converted to a bytestream) that can be saved to JSON format. In order to do so, you need to first convert your array into something that *can*, using something like `ndarray.tolist()`. Please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850511/305689) for specifics.