# Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, flask, scikit-learn

I am new to python and machine learning. I have a Linear Regression model which is able to predict output based on the input which I have dumped to be used with a web service. See the code below:

```
      X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

        regression_model = LinearRegression()
        regression_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(regression_model.predict(np.array([[21, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]))) # this is returning my expected output

joblib.dump(regression_model, '../trainedModels/MyTrainedModel.pkl')
```

Using flask I am trying this to expose as a web service as below:

```
 @app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():


    X = [[21, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
    model = joblib.load('../trainedModels/MyTrainedModel.pkl')
    prediction = model.predict(np.array(X).tolist())
    return jsonify({'prediction': list(prediction)})
```

But it is throwing the following exception

```
Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable
```

I tried [NumPy array is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable)

but still the same error. How can i solve this issue

Comment: What's the shape & dtype of `prediction` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to convert your `ndarray` with `tolist()` method:

```
prediction = model.predict(np.array(X).tolist()).tolist()
return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
```

---

Example with `json` package:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).tolist()
json.dumps({"prediction": a})
```

That should output:

```
'{"prediction": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}'
```

Comment: Thanks @mxmt. You saved my day :)

Comment: @user1188867 You are welcome! Also, read the comments in this [discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10494). Briefly, `list()` does not convert types to native Python ones. So, it's not a "safe" function for JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [simple module](https://pypi.org/project/jdata/) to export complex data structures in python:

```
pip install jdata
```

then

```
import jdata as jd;
import numpy as np; 
a={'str':'test','num':1.2,'np':np.arange(1,5,dtype=np.uint8)}; 
jd.show(a);
jd.save(a,'test.json');
```