# How to save an array of objects to a file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, save, pickle

I know how to save an **array of simple data** (like float type values) to a file using **[numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)** and [**numpy.savez**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez).

I also know how to save a **single object** to a file using the [**pickle**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, although I have not tested it yet.

The question is: How can I save (and load) an **array of objects** to a file? Can I combine the two methods exposed above in order to achieve this? Is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850511/3923163

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of that array of objects?  Have you tried `np.save`?  To load it you may need to use the `allow_pickle` parameter.  Read the docs for both `save` and `load`.

Comment: You can create a list of objects. List is a single object. You know how to save a single object with pickle :)

Comment: @hpaulj the shape would be (-1, 3) (array of triplets) and I forgot that every element of the triplet is of a different type (class A, int, class B), so I think I shouldn't use numpy arrays but rather normal python lists.

Comment: @sanyash didn't think about that. I suppose I can order my data as a list of triplets (lists) where each element is an object. This way the whole data structure will be a Python list and I should be able to save it using the pickle module. I'll try it and update the question with my results. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @sanyash I tested it and it works! I pack all my data into a single Python array and save and load it using the pickle module with no problems at all. Please, post  your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to pickle a single object, to pickle some amount of objects you can create a structure that contains all these objects (`list`, `set`, `dict` with these objects as values for example, or your own class which contains them in some way) and this structure will be a single object awailable to pickle.