# How to save augmented MNIST dataset to file?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, scikit-learn, save, mnist

I performed data augmentation on the MNIST dataset of the sklearn library. Now I want to save the augmented dataset to file, since its computation is quite long.

I want to save it in a format similar to the original MNIST which is of type `sklearn.utils.Bunch` or a dictionary so that the general form `X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target'];` to retrieve the data is preserved,

How can I do that?

```
import matplotlib;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml;
mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784");
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target'];
y = y.astype(int);
....
X_augmented, y_augmented = expand_dataset(X,y);
data_augmented = {"data": X_train_augmented, "target": y_train_augmented};
How to save to file?
```

I tried something like

```
import json
f = open("MNIST_augmented","w");
json.dump(data_augmented, f);
f.close();
```

But I get the error

> TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not specific to MNIST. If you want to store ndarray data as JSON, then you will have to do a bit more pre-processing. See here - [NumPy array is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable)

Otherwise, you should be able to use numpy.save() or pickle directly with your dictionary.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html
https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle