# Flask jsonify returns bytes and string instead of json object

Tags: python, json, api, flask, jsonify

In Postman post_new_cafe prints json as it suppose to be, but when I want to print it inside console and webpage it prints differently. See example below.

```
@app.route('/add_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_new_cafe_form():
    form = CafeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        response = post_new_cafe()
        print(response)
    return render_template("add.html", form=form)
```

This prints out

*<Response 52 bytes [200 OK]>*

and

```
@app.route('/add_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_new_cafe_form():
    form = CafeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        response = post_new_cafe()
        print(response.response)
    return render_template("add.html", form=form)
```

prints out

*[b'{\n  "success": "Successfully added the new cafe."\n}\n']*

and this

```
@app.route('/add_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_new_cafe_form():
    form = CafeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        response = post_new_cafe()
        print(response.json())
    return render_template("add.html", form=form)
```

gives error

*TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable*

This is function that returns jsonify

```
# # HTTP POST - Create Record
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def post_new_cafe():
    new_cafe = Cafe(
        name=request.form.get('name'),
        map_url=request.form.get('map_url'),
        img_url=request.form.get('img_url'),
        location=request.form.get('location'),
        seats=request.form.get('seats'),
        has_toilet=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('has_toilet'))),
        has_wifi=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('has_wifi'))),
        has_sockets=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('has_sockets'))),
        can_take_calls=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('can_take_calls'))),
        coffee_price=request.form.get('coffee_price')
    )
    # db.session.add(new_cafe)
    # db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(success="Successfully added the new cafe.")
```

I have tried this

```
resp = Response(response={"success":"Successfully added the new cafe."},
                status=200,
                mimetype="application/json")
return jsonify(resp)
```

and it's not working, also I have tried using make_response still nothing.

**What I want is when I store post_new_cafe() into response variable to have this**

```
response = post_new_cafe()
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

*{"success": "Successfully added the new cafe."}*

```
print(data["success"])
```

*Successfully added the new cafe.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can solve this issue with the json library.

Example:

```
import json

def post_new_cafe():
    new_cafe = Cafe(
        name=request.form.get('name'),
        map_url=request.form.get('map_url'),
        img_url=request.form.get('img_url'),
        location=request.form.get('location'),
        seats=request.form.get('seats'),
        has_toilet=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('has_toilet'))),
        has_wifi=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('has_wifi'))),
        has_sockets=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('has_sockets'))),
        can_take_calls=bool(strtobool(request.form.get('can_take_calls'))),
        coffee_price=request.form.get('coffee_price')
    )
    return json.dumps({"success": "Succesfully added the new cafe."})

response = post_new_cafe()
data = json.loads(response)
print(data)
print(data["success"])
```

For more information look at the [Documentation about JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

If you need to serialize a numpy array, there is a question on [how to serialize a numpy array as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable)

Regarding your other issue:

```
@app.route('/add_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_new_cafe_form():
    form = CafeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        response = post_new_cafe()
        print(response.json())
    return render_template("add.html", form=form)
```

You need to convert the response from binary to string first: `response.decode('utf-8')` and then parse it as JSON: `json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Using json and dumps() then loads() solved my problem but now I have to change all returns that returns jsonify, I guess that's what I'm going to do tonight haha. Thank you so much for the help.