# Python Jsonify returns text/html

Tags: python, flask, jsonify

I have a python application which returns a bunch of league fixtures:

```
class Fixture:
    def __init__(self, matchday, date, home_team, away_team, predicted_winner, spread):
        self.matchday = matchday
        self.date = date
        self.home_team = home_team
        self.away_team = away_team
        self.predicted_winner = predicted_winner
        self.spread = spread
```

```
import json


class League:
    def __init__(self, name, fixtures):
        self.name = name
        self.fixtures = fixtures

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "fixtures": [fixture.to_dict() for fixture in self.fixtures]
        }

class LeagueEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, League):
            return {
                "name": obj.name,
                "fixtures": [fixture.__dict__ for fixture in obj.fixtures]
            }
        return super().default(obj)
```

These objects are returned from a Flask API using jsonify:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
from services import results_calculator

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/results/<date_from>/<date_to>')
def get_results(date_from, date_to):
    fixture_results = results_calculator.calculate_results(date_from, date_to)
    return Response(jsonify(fixture_results), mimetype='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I have a Java application which invokes this endpoint:

```
List<LeagueFixtures> fixtures = webClient
    .get()
    .uri(requestUri)
    .accept(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(List.class)
    .block();
```

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class LeagueFixtures {
    private String name;
    private List<Fixture> fixtures;
}
```

```
package com.footballpredictor.predictoragent.model.input;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Fixture {
    private String date;
    private Long matchday;
    private String home_team;
    private String away_team;
    private String predicted_winner;
    private Double spread;
}
```

However when the code hits, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html;charset=utf-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.List<?>
> at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:205) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
> Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
> Error has been observed at the following site(s):
> *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:5000/results/2023-06-02/2023-06-05 [DefaultClientResponse]

Am I missing something that is causing the jsonify function to be ignored?

In the flask API I have tried:

- Returning json.dumps(fixture_results, League_Encoder)
- Simply returning jsonify
- I tried the answer from here:
  [Flask jsonify returns bytes and string instead of json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887502/flask-jsonify-returns-bytes-and-string-instead-of-json-object)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
return Response(jsonify(fixture_results), mimetype='application/json')
```

is not how you are supposed to use `jsonify`, as [`jsonify` docs](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.jsonify.html) reveals

> It turns the JSON output into a Response object with the
> application/json mimetype.

So you should use it following way

```
return jsonify(fixture_results)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already tried this and I'm still seeing the same issue.

I tried updating it to this again but got the error still:
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html;charset=utf-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.List<?>
 at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:205) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: