# How to convert a multi-dimensional dictionary to json file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, matlab, dictionary

I have uploaded a *.mat file that contains a 'struct' to my jupyter lab using:

```
from pymatreader import read_mat
data = read_mat(mat_file)
```

Now I have a multi-dimensional dictionary, for example:

```
data['Forces']['Ss1']['flap'].keys()
```

Gives the output:

```
dict_keys(['lf', 'rf', 'lh', 'rh'])
```

I want to convert this into a JSON file, exactly by the keys that already exist, without manually do so because I want to perform it to many *.mat files with various key numbers.

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I no longer have access to MATLAB.
An example for desired output would look something like this:

```
json_format = {
"Forces": {
  "Ss1": {
    "flap": {
      "lf": [1,2,3,4],
      "rf": [4,5,6,7],
      "lh": [23 ,5,6,654,4],
      "rh": [4 ,34 ,35, 56, 66]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

ANOTHER EDIT:
So after making lists of the subkeys (I won't elaborate on it), I did this:

```
FORCES = []
for ind in individuals:
  for force in forces:
    for wing in wings:
      FORCES.append({
          ind: {
              force: {
                  wing: data['Forces'][ind][force][wing].tolist()
 
              }
          }
      })
```

Then, to save:

```
with open(f'{ROOT_PATH}/Forces.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(FORCES, f)
```

That worked but only because I looked manually for all of the keys... Also, for some reason, I have squared brackets at the beginning and at the end of this json file.

Comment: Can you add an example of you expected json file?

Answer (score 3):

The `json` package will output dictionaries to JSON:

```
import json

with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: I get an TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: Now TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable... I'm starting to think it is undoable

Comment: These errors are because in addition to numeric values, you also have byte or Numpy arrays that have to be converted before being serialized to JSON. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MATLAB-R2016b or later, and want to go straight from MATLAB to JSON check out [`JSONENCODE`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) and [`JSONDECODE`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondencode.html). For your purposes `JSONENCODE`

> encodes data and returns a character vector in JSON format.
> [MathWorks Docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html)

Here is a quick example that assumes your data is in the MATLAB variable `test_data` and writes it to a file specified in the variable `json_file`

```
json_data = jsonencode(test_data);
writematrix(json_data,json_file);
```

**Note:** Some MATLAB data formats cannot be translate into JSON data due to limitations in the JSON specification. However, it sounds like your data fits well with the JSON specification.