# What is the cleanest way to perform nested conversion of numpy types to python (JSON friendly) types?

Tags: json, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-typing

What is the cleanest way to perform *nested* conversion of a "deep" object that contains mixed python / numpy types to an object containing only python types?

The question is motivated by the need to send the data as JSON, but here I do not have control over json.dumps() because that is the province of a different application. In other words, I cannot specify the JSON encoder.

One possible solution involves adopting [the JSON encoder solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable) anyway, followed by a conversion back to JSON with json.loads(). This would mean every message has two round trips to JSON rather than one which might not be the end of the way. But is there a "better" alternative?

Note that I need to apply recursively so that fact that tolist() or item() sometimes works isn't a complete solution here.

Comment: Arrays have an efficient `tolist` method.  Of course it's most useful for numeric dtypes.  It doesn't do anything to elements of object dtype arrays.

Comment: From the question you linked, I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52604722/4601890) the best, most clean

Comment: The issue though is that you still have to walk the object no?