# How to convert Python numpy array to base64 output

Tags: python, arrays, base64

I basically need to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string) but in Python instead of Javascript.  I receive a base64 encoded string from a socketio connection, convert it to uint8 and work on it, then need to convert it to base64 string so I can send it back.

So, up to this point I've got this (I'm getting the `data` dictionary from the socketio server):

```
import pickle
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

base64_image_string = data["image"]
image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_image_string)))
img = np.array(image)
```

How do I reverse this process to get from `img` back to `base64_image_string`?

**UPDATE:**
I have solved this in the following manner (continuing from the code snippet above):

```
pil_img = Image.fromarray(img)
buff = BytesIO()
pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
new_image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
```

Somewhat confusingly, `new_image_string` is not identical to `base64_image_string` but the image rendered from `new_image_string` looks the same so I'm satisfied!

Comment: It seems that `save` to `JPEG` is a loss function. The then decoded image string is no longer equivalent to the original image.

Comment: @MeadowMuffins Just use another format that is lossless, for example PNG

Answer (score 15):

I believe since `numpy.array`s support the buffer protocol, you just need the following:

```
processed_string = base64.b64encode(img)
```

So, for example:

```
>>> encoded = b"aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxk"
>>> img = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(encoded), np.uint8)
>>> img
array([104, 101, 108, 108, 111,  44,  32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100], dtype=uint8)
>>> img.tobytes()
b'hello, world'
>>> base64.b64encode(img)
b'aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxk'
>>>
```

Comment: This is amazing! BUT, when I deserialize, my 3-D `numpy` array comes out as 1-D only - must I `reshape` using values for the original shape carried with the array, or is there a way that circumvents `reshape`? Thx!

Comment: It's quite ugly but I ended up doing: `payload = ('nparr',img.shape,base64.b64encode(img.copy(order='C')))` and deserializing correspondingly. Is there a way around this? Huge thanks!

Comment: @jtlz2 no,  but have you considered another serialization method like [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html1)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that route (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925741/1021819) - but in the end I thought it safer to use base64 over the wire than a byte string. Do you have a view on which is preferable?

Comment: @jtlz2 sorry, but I dont really follow. Base64 produces a byte string. And it is safer in  what sense? `numpy.save` is much much more portable across platforms, taking care of things like byte-order along with shape out if the box. If I was choosing with no arbitrary restrictions, I would undoubtedly use `numpy.save` over base64 encoding. It's probably faster, and definitely less memory intensive

Comment: Thanks! Went down this route in the end - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948073/1021819

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. After some search and try, my final solution is almost the same as yours.

The only difference is that the base64 encoded string is `png` format data, so I need to change it from `RGBA` to `RGB` channels before converted to np.array:

```
image = image.convert ("RGB")
img = np.array(image)
```

In the reverse process, you treate the data as `JPEG` format, maybe this is the reason why `new_image_string` is not identical to `base64_image_string` ?

Answer (score -1):

from http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/convert-image-to-string-in-python/ :

```
import base64

with open("t.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print str
```

is binary read

https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

Comment: Wait, why would you have to convert the `numpy` array to utf-8?

Comment: the base64 alphabet is "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="  *Base64 ist ein Verfahren zur Kodierung von 8-Bit-Binärdaten (z. B. ausführbare Programme, ZIP-Dateien oder Bilder)* this translates as *Base 64 is a standard to encode 8-bit binary data (i.e. executables, ZIP files or images)*

Comment: ... yes, so what?

Comment: it's an array of byes (uint8). See the example I posted. In any event, I'm not sure why you think converting to *utf8* would help...

Comment: ok nice i did not know that numpy arrays are structured on bytes because normally i use them with composed datatypes like float, integer,...

Comment: well... a 32-bit float or integer is just a sequence of 4 byte chunks... a 64 bit integer or float is a sequence of 8-byte chunks... a 8-bit integer is a sequence of 1-byte chunks... Numpy arrays are basically object-oriented wrappers around C arrays with a bunch of handy routines built-in.

Comment: yes, i know tis and exactly this is the reason why i think that conversion to utf-8 would help. Because if the image in the numpy array is not binary coded but instead integer, float,.. then the base64 encoded string would contain wrong data because of the binary read...

Comment: however normally images are encoded in RGB or other **byte-oriented** standards and so you are right...