# Concatenating strings in Python - What is the fastest way

Tags: python, numpy

I need to send an image over a socket and I need to do it as fast as possible.
The image represented as 3d numpy array.
The data that is sent can get over 500000 bytes.

As of now, i do it like this:

```
array_data_type = image.dtype.name
array_shape = image.shape
to_send = array_data_shape + SEPARATOR + cPickle.dumps(array_shape) + SEPARATOR + image.tobytes()
streaming_socket.sendall(to_send)
```

The concatenation takes now about 0.044sec and i want it to be faster. Can it be faster?

Comment: Have you figured out which step is eating up your time?  Is it for sure the concatenation or is it possible that it's cPickle.dumps() or image.tobytes()?

Comment: image.tobytes() is eating the time

Comment: It looks like @chepner answered this question but you might want to ask a follow up about speeding up the tobytes() function.

Comment: Is there an alternative for tobytes() function?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925624/fastest-method-to-dump-numpy-array-into-string  I'm not sure if any of those suggestions is faster.

Comment: John you are a legend :) one of those suggestions was faster. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `join` method to create a single `str` result, rather than a series of temporary `str` objects as you evaluate each `+` operation.

```
to_send = SEPARATOR.join([array_data_shape, cPickle.dumps(array_shape), image.tobytes()])
```

Your current code is equivalent to

```
tmp1 = array_data_shape + SEPARATOR
tmp2 = tmp1 + cPickle.dumps(array_shape)
tmp3 = tmp2 + SEPARATOR
to_send = tmp3 + image.tobytes()
```

and each `+` has to copy both its arguments into the new `str` it constructs. The running time is quadratic in the length of the final result*, while `SEPARATOR.join` is linear.

---

* Assuming the things you are joining are roughly equal in size, anyway. Strictly speaking, each `+` is linear in the size of its arguments, and the number of times an individual item gets copied is proportional to how far left it is. Assuming that `xi` represents the size of the `i`th string, the total work done is `(x1 + x2) + (x1 + x2 + x3) + ... + (x1 + x2 + ... + xn)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it soon.