# How I can serialize the json in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, numpy, serialization

Here is the code and the error follows:

```
import numpy as np
import json
X=np.arange(20)
t=dict(x=list(X))
print(json.dumps(t))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
```

Please let me know what I can do to get rid of this. I am trying to pass this value to the plotting windows and the same error is occurring.

Comment: For a more generic approach to serializing `numpy` data, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909658/json-encoder-and-decoder-for-complex-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json values are not properly type cast I guess.  tried to find something related to your query: [TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable](https://github.com/automl/SMAC3/issues/453#issuecomment-426933082)

You just need to type cast it:

```
>>> t = dict(x=list(float(j) for j in X))
>>> json.dumps(t)
'{"x": [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0]}'
```

I guess that will work.

Comment: `X.tolist()` is faster and easier.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy-ndarray-tolist)<sup>numpy.org</sup> method. This will

> return a copy of the array data as a (nested) Python list. For a 1D
> array, `a.tolist()` is almost the same as `list(a)`.However, for a 2D
> array, `tolist` applies recursively

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import json

>>> X = np.arange(20)
>>> t = dict(x=X.tolist())
>>> print(json.dumps(t))
{"x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]}
```

Comment: `list()` returns numbers wrapped in numpy types.  That's creating the json problem.   `tolist` unpacks them all the way.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's because `json` doesn't recognize the numpy data type.

I tried this code and it worked.

```
import json
t= {'x': [i for i in range(20)]}
print(json.dumps(t))
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach mapping `int` on array

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np
import json
X=np.arange(20)
t=dict(x=list(map(int, X)))
print(json.dumps(t))
```