# Fastest way to parse JSON strings into numpy arrays

Tags: python, json, numpy, cython

I have huge json objects containing 2D lists of coordinates that I need to transform into numpy arrays for processing.

However using `json.loads` followed with `np.array()` is too slow.

Is there a way to increase the speed of creation of numpy arrays from json?

```
import json
import numpy as np

json_input = '{"rings" : [[[-8081441.0, 5685214.0], [-8081446.0, 5685216.0], [-8081442.0, 5685219.0], [-8081440.0, 5685211.0], [-8081441.0, 5685214.0]]]}'

dict = json.loads(json_input)
numpy_2d_arrays = [np.array(ring) for ring in dict["rings"]]
```

I would take any solution whatsoever!

Comment: I'm getting a `json` decoder error: `  File "/usr/lib/python3.5,...
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 14 (char 13)`

Comment: @hpaulj you are right, it's fixed

Comment: It was the `()` which were non-standard JSON.

Comment: Other parsers are `eval` and `ast.literal_eval` (safer).  On this small sample `json.loads` is noticeably faster.  The `np.array` part takes even less time.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer would just be:

```
numpy_2d_arrays = np.array(dict["rings"])
```

As this avoids explicitly looping over your array in python you would probably see a modest speedup. If you have control over the creation of `json_input` it would be better to write out as a serial array. A version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488934/simplejson-and-numpy-array).

Answer (score 4):

Since JSON syntax is really near to Python syntax, I suggest you to use `ast.literal_eval`. It may be faster…

```
import ast
import numpy as np

json_input = """{"rings" : [[[-8081441.0, 5685214.0],
                             [-8081446.0, 5685216.0],
                             [-8081442.0, 5685219.0],
                             [-8081440.0, 5685211.0],
                             [-8081441.0, 5685214.0]]]}"""

rings = ast.literal_eval(json_input)
numpy_2d_arrays = [np.array(ring) for ring in rings["rings"]]
```

Give it a try. And tell us.

Comment: Thank you but ast.literal_eval is slower than json.loads() with my data

Answer (score 3):

For this specific data, you could try this

```
import numpy as np

json_input = '{"rings" : [[(-8081441.0, 5685214.0), (-8081446.0, 5685216.0), (-8081442.0, 5685219.0), (-8081440.0, 5685211.0), (-8081441.0, 5685214.0)]]}'
i = json_input.find('[')
L = eval(json_input[i+1:-2])
print(np.array(L))
```

Comment: using eval is unsafe

Comment: @ei-grad It depends on the context. Python has always been made for consenting adults!