# Making numpy arrays JSON serializable

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, numpy

I have a program which handles data in the form of NumPy arrays, which needs to be stored in JSON form (to later pass it to another program to visualize the data). When I try the following:

```
my_array = np.array([3, 4, 5])
json.dumps(my_array)
```

I get an error message reading

```
TypeError: array([3, 4, 5]) is not JSON serializable
```

So it turns out that arrays are not serializable. I hoped to solve this by converting the arrays into ordinary lists, but if I try

```
my_array = np.array([3, 4, 5])
my_list = list(my_array)
json.dumps(my_list)
```

I just get an error reading

```
TypeError: 3 is not JSON serializable
```

(That `3` appears to be because '3' is the first element of the list)

Even stranger, this error persists when I try to reconstruct a list from scratch:

```
def plain_list(ls):
  pl = []
  for element in ls:
    pl.append(element)
  return pl

my_array = np.array([3, 4, 5])
my_list = plain_list(my_array)
json.dumps(my_list)
```

still returns

```
TypeError: 3 is not JSON serializable
```

I have two questions:

1. How is it that even that last one doesn't work? Shouldn't it have 'forgotten' everything about having ever been a NumPy array? Are integers in NumPy arrays not *really* the same objects as ordinary integers, and do they carry some special invisible property with them that persists even outside of the array?
2. How *can* I effectively store arrays in JSON form (no matter how convoluted the solution may need to be)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That `3` is a [NumPy integer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html) that displays like a regular Python int, but isn't one. Use [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy.ndarray.tolist) to get a list of ordinary Python ints:

```
json.dumps(my_array.tolist())
```

This will also convert multidimensional arrays to nested lists, so you don't have to deal with a 3-layer list comprehension for a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: In addition to user2357112's correct answer about how to specifically get your code working, consider extending `json` to be able to encode your array as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24375113/3171657).